# Get data from parent Structure Group

Tags: structuregroups

**my requirements:**

- A way to list all Structure Groups within current level (or by parent)
- A way to list all child Pages within current Structure Group
- A way to get all meta tags (`filterCategory`) from all child Pages within products Structure Group

Basically I am building a Page filter, which purpose is to filter products on a product/news list Page.

It has a topmenu for navigation between different lists + meta tags that exist within each Page, to show/hide products on the list Page with JavaScript.

```
- Products (Structure Group)
-- Product Page (Page with Components)
-- Product list 1 (Structure Group)
-- Product list 2 (Structure Group)
-- Product list 3 (Structure Group)
```

Using Tridion 2013

Tips and tricks much appreciated.

I was thinking of using the Content Delivery (JSP) to do this.
Is this the best way?

Comment: Please **edit** your question and provide some more details. Do you want to do this with TOM.NET (for publishing), with a Core Service script, or in the Content Delivery side?

Comment: I was thinking of combining razor and jsp code. I am fearly new to Tridion and the concepts of working with this CMS. So I might be looking for that answer myself.

Comment: We tend to have a template that pushes this hierarchical information and any additional metadata to the delivery side (like in JSON or XML) and then use that as input for your "widget"

Comment: How do I do that then?

Answer (score 2):

```
[TcmTemplateTitle("XML")]
public class XMLTemplate : TemplateBase
{
    public override void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
    {
        base.Transform(engine, package);


        OrganizationalItemItemsFilter filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilter(engine.GetSession());
        filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.StructureGroup, ItemType.Page };
        filter.Recursive = true;
        filter.BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended;            

        // Retrieve only items from the root structure group
        XmlElement list = Publication.RootStructureGroup.GetListItems(filter);

    //TODO: Loop through all the list and build the pages and URLs as XML Refer TOM.NET for SDL APIs Page, Component, and metadata objects

        package.AddXml(Package.OutputName, xxxxx.OuterXml);
    }
}
```